# Function to classify address as EU or non-EU

Tags: php, object-oriented, comparative-review, geospatial

`LeadDetails` class:

```
namespace App\Services\Lead\LeadDetails;

use App\Library\Localization\Currency;
use App\Services\Lead\LeadDetails\MovingServices;
use App\Services\Lead\VersionId;

final class LeadDetails
{
    /**
     * @var VersionId
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var MovingAppointment
     */
    private $origin;

    /**
     * @var MovingAppointment
     */
    private $destination;

    /**
     * @var MovingServices\Stopovers
     */
    private $stopovers;

    /**
     * @var MovingServices\ParkingBan
     */
    private $parkingBan;

    /**
     * @var MovingServices\Storage
     */
    private $storage;

    /**
     * @var MovingServices\Insurance
     */
    private $insurance;

    /**
     * @var MovingServices\Kitchen
     */
    private $kitchen;

    /**
     * @var Comments
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @var Distance
     */
    private $distance;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $accountManager;

    /**
     * @var \App\Library\Localization\Currency
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @var MovingServices\Cleaning
     */
    private $cleaning;

    /**
     * @param VersionId $id
     * @param MovingAppointment $origin
     * @param MovingAppointment $destination
     * @param MovingServices\Stopovers $stopovers
     * @param MovingServices\ParkingBan $parkingBan
     * @param MovingServices\Storage $storage
     * @param MovingServices\Insurance $insurance
     * @param MovingServices\Kitchen $kitchen
     * @param MovingServices\Cleaning $cleaning
     * @param Comments $comments
     * @param Distance $distance
     * @param Currency $currency
     * @param null $accountManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        VersionId $id,
        MovingAppointment $origin,
        MovingAppointment $destination,
        MovingServices\Stopovers $stopovers,
        MovingServices\ParkingBan $parkingBan,
        MovingServices\Storage $storage,
        MovingServices\Insurance $insurance,
        MovingServices\Kitchen $kitchen,
        MovingServices\Cleaning $cleaning,
        Comments $comments,
        Distance $distance,
        Currency $currency,
        $accountManager = null
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->origin = $origin;
        $this->destination = $destination;
        $this->stopovers = $stopovers;
        $this->storage = $storage;
        $this->parkingBan = $parkingBan;
        $this->insurance = $insurance;
        $this->kitchen = $kitchen;
        $this->cleaning = $cleaning;
        $this->comments = $comments;
        $this->distance = $distance;
        $this->accountManager = $accountManager;
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return VersionId
     */
    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingAppointment
     */
    public function origin()
    {
        return $this->origin;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingAppointment
     */
    public function destination()
    {
        return $this->destination;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingServices\Stopovers
     */
    public function stopovers()
    {
        return $this->stopovers;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingServices\ParkingBan
     */
    public function parkingBan()
    {
        return $this->parkingBan;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingServices\Storage
     */
    public function storage()
    {
        return $this->storage;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingServices\Insurance
     */
    public function insurance()
    {
        return $this->insurance;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingServices\Kitchen
     */
    public function kitchen()
    {
        return $this->kitchen;
    }

    /**
     * @return MovingServices\Cleaning
     */
    public function cleaning()
    {
        return $this->cleaning;
    }

    /**
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * @return Distance
     */
    public function distance()
    {
        return $this->distance;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function accountManager()
    {
        return $this->accountManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return Currency
     */
    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCrossBorder()
    {
        return $this->origin->countryId() != $this->destination->countryId();
    }
}
```

`MovingAppointment` class:

```
namespace App\Services\Lead\LeadDetails;

use App\Library\Lead\Values\AppointmentDate;
use App\Library\Lead\Values\AppointmentTime;
use App\Library\System\ArrayData;
use App\Library\Values\Address;

final class MovingAppointment
{
    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $countryId;

    /**
     * @var AppointmentDate
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var ArrayData
     */
    private $appartment;
    /**
     * @var AppointmentTime
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @param Address $address
     * @param string $countryId
     * @param AppointmentDate $date
     * @param ArrayData $appartment
     * @param AppointmentTime|null $time
     */
    public function __construct(
        Address $address,
        $countryId,
        AppointmentDate $date,
        ArrayData $appartment,
        AppointmentTime $time = null
    )
    {
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->countryId = $countryId;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->appartment = $appartment;
        $this->time = $time;
    }

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function countryId()
    {
        return $this->countryId;
    }

    public function date()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function appartment()
    {
        return $this->appartment;
    }

    public function time()
    {
        return $this->time;
    }
}
```

`Address` class:

```
namespace App\Library\Values;

use App\Library\System\ArrayData;

final class Address
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $postalCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @param string $street
     * @param string $city
     * @param string $postalCode
     * @param string $country
     */
    public function __construct($street, $city, $postalCode, $country)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;
        $this->country = $country;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function street()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function postalCode()
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'street' => $this->street,
            'zip_code' => $this->postalCode,
            'city' => $this->city,
            'country' => $this->country,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return Address
     */
    public static function fromArray(array $data)
    {
        $data = new ArrayData($data);
        return new self(
            $data->get('street'),
            $data->get('city'),
            $data->get('zip_code'),
            $data->get('country')
        );
    }
}
```

`CountryType` class:

```
namespace App\Library\System;

class isEuCountry
{

    private $euCountries = [
        'AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CH', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'EL',
        'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV',
        'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK'
    ];

    /**
     * @var CountryCode
     */
    private $countryCode;

    /**
     * @param CountryCode $countryCode
     */
    public function __construct(CountryCode $countryCode)
    {
        $this->countryCode = $countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function applies()
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($this->countryCode), $this->euCountries);
    }

}
```

I want to create a functions called:

```
public function isEu()
{
  return (new isEuCountry(**COUNTRY_CODE**))->applies();
}
```

Where in which level should I create this function, and why?

Shall I create it in the `LeadDetails` class:

```
public function isEu()
{
   return (new isEuCountry($this->origin->address->country())->applies();
}
```

Or shall I create it in the `Address` class?

```
public function isEu()
{
   return (new isEuCountry($this->address->country())->applies();
}
```

Comment: You have not documented your code in any way. The comments that are there are useless. Documentation is important. It should answer the questions like: What is this code for? What does it do? We can only answer your questions if we have an idea what the purpose of the code is. Something about moving appointments to clean kitchens while making sure one doesn't get a parking ticket?

Comment: Disagree with @KIKOSoftware  Certainly, I think the OP could add more information to the post about what the context of these classes are within the application, but I would not mistake us not being given context on the role of these classes in the application as the comments in the code itself being inappropriate. Good code should not need a lot of comments, because class names, method names, variable names, etc. should be self-explanatory.  I really just think there could have been more context given in the post itself since we don't have broader application context.

Comment: I meant explaining the context to us, and that the comments didn't help in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

My main criticism would be that I that classes really just seem to primary be dumping spots for a lot of information - especially `LeadDetails` which requires 13 parameters to be passed to the constructor, which is unusually high.  Can the classes be subdivided/refactored into a set of classes that better serve to aggregate the related information?  As they stand right now, there really isn't a whole lot of logic that is even encapsulated into these classes.

---

The `isEuCountry` class seems to have a poor data structure to store your countries. You should not need to iterate the entire array (which is what happens when you use `in_array()`) just to do a lookup.  An associative array (hash map) might be more appropriate here. So something like:

```
[
    'AT' => 'Austria',
    'BE' => 'Belgium'
    ...
]
```

This would allow indexed - O(1) - lookup by country code.

The class should probably be called `EuCountries` or similar, and have `isEuCountryCode()` method.  A class named `is*` should probably be a red flag that you have really just built a function. If you want a class for this, make it a class and name it appropriately.

This class is where you should hold any methods to validate a country code as representing a valid EU country.

---

I don't understand the need to use `ArrayData` object in `Address::fromArray()`.

---

You are making wide use of type-hinting, which is a good practice, but you perform no other validation for parameters passed to your public methods that are not able to be type hinted.

---

It is pretty standard convention to name getter methods as `get*()`.